# Generic Iterator annotations Python

Tags: python, generics, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I am trying to annotate an Iterator which only returns two values, `T` and `cls[T]`.

Currently I have it annotated like this:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
import typing


class Node(typing.Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, value: T, next: typing.Optional[Node[T]] = None) -> None:
        self.value = value 
        self.next = next

    def __iter__(self) -> typing.Iterator[typing.Union[T, Node[T]]]:
        yield from (self.value, self.next)
```

This code works without any errors. However, I wish to take advantage of the fact that this dunder method will **always** yield two values to simplify the process for the user.

As it is, the user has to deal with the following:

```py
one = Node[int](1, Node[int](2))
value, next = one # value = 1, next = Node(2) (i.e one.next)

# This is a typing error because next can be either int or Node[int] 
# and 'two' is expected to be Node[int]:
two: Node[int] = next

# we can fix this by doing type narrowing
assert isinstance(next, Node)
two = next # now the error should be gone
```

So basically I want to take advantage of the fact that the second thing returned by the `__iter__` is always of type `Node[T]` to avoid having to do type narrowing.

I know that I have to change `typing.Union[T, Node[T]]` in the method's return annotation, but I do not know what to change it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible to annotate using the generic `Iterator`. It is a class expecting exactly **one** type argument. (current [typeshed source](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stdlib/typing.pyi#L346)) That means **every** value returned by its `__next__` method necessarily has the same type.

You are invoking the iterator protocol on that tuple of `self.value, self.next`. A tuple has an **arbitrary** number of type arguments (see [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.0/Lib/typing.py#L1613)), but an iterator over it must still have exactly one. This actually leads to typing issues fairly often.

Since you seem to intend your `Node` class to essentially emulate the `tuple` interface, this may be one of the rare cases, where it is better to inherit from it directly. A `tuple` will obviously also give you the iterable protocol, so you can still unpack it as before, but the types should be inferred properly, if you do everything correctly.

Here is a full working example:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TypeVar, Optional


T = TypeVar("T")


class Node(tuple[T, "Node[T]"]):
    def __new__(cls, value: T, next_: Optional[Node[T]] = None) -> Node[T]:
        return tuple.__new__(cls, (value, next_))

    def __init__(self, value: T, next_: Optional[Node[T]] = None) -> None:
        self.value = value
        self.next = next_


if __name__ == "__main__":
    node_1 = Node(1, Node(2))
    val: int
    node_2: Node[int]
    val, node_2 = node_1
```

This passes `mypy --strict` without problems.

---

As an unrelated side note, I would advise against using built-in names like [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next).

Also, note that you do not need to specify the type argument for `Node`, when you initialize one because it is automatically *bound* to the type passed to the `value` parameter.

Comment: This is amazing! thank you so much! 

Also, thanks for the notes about variable names.

Answer (score -2):

for while are the loops that can be used and mentioned as generic iterator annotations